# No Appliaction permission support for ChannelMessage.Read.All anylonger?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I was using an app with graph api permission of ChannelMessage.Read.All.
Since 4 days (4th of july) this does not work anylonger although it was working fine the last several months.

The documentation states now, that app permission is not supported anymore.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

What's the reason why this has been removed? Any plans to get this back?
It is not practical to use delegated permission.

please help
thx
stefan

Comment: Can you please share the response that you received?

Comment: I get http 403 whenever i use the application permission of this graph api channelmesage.read.all.               
                                               Invalid response [Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=403, message=Forbidden, url=https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/d0f28f0e-9c5f-47a4-bdde-c635ccd2cfc7/channels/19:21f67b8e9f28485c8a5fbb351709af01@thread.skype/messages?$top=20}] for data request [Request{method=GET, url=https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/d0f28f0e-9c5f-47a4-bdde/channels/19:21f67b8e9f28485c8a5@thread.skype/messages?$top=20

Comment: @StefanFr- Could you please try this one more time and let us know if you are still facing this issue? [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) is updated as well.